# Considerations for choosing transformation on small samples?

Tags: data-transformation, small-sample, nonparametric

For a biological investigation, I am taking measurements of a set group of individuals over five points in time. The measurement is always between 0 and 1. Unfortunately, I was unable to measure every individual during every visit.

What I would love to do are pairwise parametric tests between each point in time, to see how the mean of these measurements change over time for this population. The problem is that for each time point, the distribution of measurements is not normal, and the sample size out of the total popuation of 62 is very different each time, from about 15 to almost the whole population. I have attached a CSV file with the data [here](http://pastebin.com/5wZZ5KPW), sorry I don't know if there is a better way to show you.

I know I might be able to run non-parametric tests such as the Wilcoxon test between each point in time. But I'd love to know if there is a way for me to choose a transformation that I can apply to all five samples to make them normally distributed so that I can also try parametric tests.

Comment: linkrot has made the linked data unavailable. It sounds like it was small enough to have been put in the post. Unfortunate. Were the values between 0 and 1 compositional data (a continuous proportion, such as the proportion of some substance in some other substance), or count-fractions?